# What is the easiest way to handle dates/times in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

My use case is that I'm just making a website that I want people all over the world to be able to use, and I want to be able to say things like "This happened at 5:33pm on October 5" and also "This happened 5 minutes ago," etc.

Should I use the datetime module? 
Or just strftime?
Or something fancier that isn't part of the std distro of Python?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the dateutil module:

http://labix.org/python-dateutil

It's good at doing the types of things you're looking for - see some of the examples in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at Django's [humanize module](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/#ref-contrib-humanize).
It is part of Django, but I think it would be quite easy to adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The datetime module in Python will allow you to get/set/manipulate dates and times. 
A question about relative date formatting in Python has already been asked: [Stack Overflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python)
but with very little responce.

Answer (score 1):

Try [relativeDates Module](http://jehiah.cz/archive/printing-relative-dates-in-python) module. It exactly brings you the stuff you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `datetime`, make sure you read this recent and most excellent article:
 [Tips on using python's datetime module](http://www.enricozini.org/2009/debian/using-python-datetime/). `datetime` will take care of most of the niceties of handling time arithmetic, but it won't give you the English-language pretty printing you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been very happy using the datetime package. You get a lot of stuff for free, and it's pretty easy to create datetime objects as well, calculate duration ect.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Time module](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html).

Comment: Not very helpful... You'll never ever get things like "5 minutes ago" out of the time module.