# converting strptime into 'X hours ago'

Tags: python, timestamp, strptime

I have a a date in strptime that I want to show as 'X hours ago'. I can happily convert hours into days and weeks etc. but I don't know how to do the initial sum. Here is how I'm converting the string into strptime:

```
time.strptime(obj.created_at, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
```

p.s. bonus points for figuring out why it won't take %z for '+0000' - am I completely wrong about what this is?

Comment: This must be one of the most common questions on SO.

Comment: I would appreciate being pointed to an example where it has already been answered in that case

Comment: I think the hint was that you could search (at the top of the page) for previous similar questions and see their answers.

Comment: got the hint, took the hint and found nothing that either fitted my problem or nothing that was suitably simple enough for me to understand

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551382/python-user-friendly-time-format, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096396/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-handle-dates-times-in-python, etc.  There are dozens.

Comment: @chrism: If none of the other question fit your problem, please provide details showing the other questions and what's different about your question.

Answer (score 4):

It seems the [`timesince`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) in Django could help you out without you having to convert. The source for `timesince` is available [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/timesince.py).

Comment: Defined here: http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/timesince.py

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using zope rather the django, I've looked for something like this in zope, but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2):

The `datetime` module is definitely easier to use, but, if you insist, you can do it with the `time` module instead.  I.e.:

```
>>> import time
>>> fmt = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'
>>> time.strftime(fmt)
'Thu Oct 15 07:54:07 +0000 2009'
>>> createdat = 'Thu Oct 15 02:30:30 +0000 2009'
>>> createdtim = time.strptime(createdat, fmt)
>>> hoursago = (time.time() - time.mktime(createdtim)) / 3600
>>> print hoursago
5.42057559947
```

One reason the `time` module is so pesky to use is that it uses two different ways to represent time -- one is a 9-tuple (and that's what you get from `strptime`), and one is a float "seconds since the epoch" (and that's what you need to do differences); the `mktime` function translates the former to the latter.  Difference in hours is clearly 1/3600 of the difference in seconds -- you'll have to decide how to display a typically-fractionary "number of hours ago", of course (hour and fraction with some digits, or, round to closest integer number of hours, or what else).

The literal '+0000' in your format, for `strptime`, means you expect and ignore those literal characters at that spot in your "createdat" string (normally you'd have a timezone offset specifier there).  If that's indeed what you want, then you have the right format string!

Answer (score 0):

Can you use datetime instead? (Or convert whatever you have into datetime?)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> created_at = datetime.datetime(2009,10,15, 13)
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> delta = now - created_at
>>> hours_ago = '%d Hours Ago' % (delta.seconds/60/60)
>>> hours_ago
'5 Hours Ago'
```

Comment: I think I'm going to need to read up about datetime, for a rookie it's a bit of a mind bender, and not something that I can just borrow from an example

Comment: datetime makes dates/times much more manageable, I rarely find myself using time.

Comment: The code is just subtracting the created_at time from the time now, so that we have delta.seconds ago, then changing delta.seconds to hours by dividing by secs/min and min/hour.