# Convert date to months and year

Tags: python

From the following dates how to get months and year using python

dates are

```
           "2011-07-01 09:26:11"   //This showud display  as "This month"
           "2011-06-07 09:26:11"   //This should display as June            
           "2011-03-12 09:26:11"   //This should display as March            
           "2010-07-25 09:26:11"   // Should display as last year
```

Please let me know how to get these formats using python 2.4

When I have a date variable[with same format] in pandas dataframe, how to perform this ?

Comment: ` // Should display as last year` is not a comment in python

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python/5164027#5164027 and work from there.

Comment: I could give an answer here, that's not to hard. But, please provide some own efforts first. Python's [datetime docs](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) are quite helpful. If they don't help you, come back and ask for a solution to your particular problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import time
import calendar

current = time.localtime()

dates = ["2011-07-01 09:26:11", "2011-06-07 09:26:11", "2011-03-12 09:26:11", "2010-07-25 09:26:11"]

for date in dates:
    print "%s" % date
    date = time.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

    if date.tm_year == current.tm_year - 1:
        print "Last year"    

    elif date.tm_mon == current.tm_mon:
        print "This month"

    else:
        print calendar.month_name[date.tm_mon]
```

Should do roughly what you ask for.

Answer (score 3):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = datetime.strptime('2011-07-01 09:26:11', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
if a.month == datetime.now().month:
    print 'This month'
```

The other results according to http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html

Answer (score 0):

Good site for python date/time conversions:
http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-datetime-time-conversions/

Answer (score -2):

You could use datetime.strptime to paste the date. 
But for simple case like yours, i would just use regex.

```
>>>> import re
>>>> re.match('^(\d+)-(\d+)', "2011-07-01 09:26:11").groups()
('2011', '07')
```

Comment: I don't think this is simpler than `d = datetime.strptime("2011-07-01 09:26:11", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"); (d.year, d.month)`.

Comment: Why use re when you don't have to.