# Render different date format depending on time that passed - either |timesince or |date

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

Good morning. What I would like to achive is that when user posted sooner than 24h from now, I would like to have for example:
`Posted: 4h ago`, but when it's more than 24h, it would be nice to have: `Posted: November 10.`

First approach is doable by using: `{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}`, second one: `{{ post.date_posted|timesince }}`, but is there a way to "mix" them? Is is possible in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own `time_utils.py` in an app called `custom_utils`  like below based on stack overflow posts. You can modify it accordingly.

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def prettydate(d):
    if d is not None:
        diff = timezone.now() - d
        s = diff.seconds
        if diff.days > 30 or diff.days < 0:
            return d.strftime('Y-m-d H:i')
        elif diff.days == 1:
            return 'One day ago'
        elif diff.days > 1:
            return '{} days ago'.format(diff.days)
        elif s <= 1:
            return 'just now'
        elif s < 60:
            return '{} seconds ago'.format(s)
        elif s < 120:
            return 'one minute ago'
        elif s < 3600:
            return '{} minutes ago'.format(round(s/60))
        elif s < 7200:
            return 'one hour ago'
        else:
            return '{} hours ago'.format(round(s/3600))
    else:
        return None
```

then in the app models, I do:

```
from custom_utils.time_utils import prettydate

class ForumPost(models.Model):
# your other fields
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
# your other fields

    def pretty_published_date(self):
        return prettydate(self.published_date)
```

reference: #[Natural/Relative days in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python)
Jose Segall's answer

**EDIT:** I faced a problem when querying a dataset using annotate, I was not able to use attributes such as the `pretty_published_date`. I had to use custom template tags. The following is how to **implement `prettydate` function to custom template tags.**

1. Create `templatetags` folder in one of the app which is in INSTALLED_APPS in settings file of the project. I put mine under `forum` folder.
2. Create a blank `__init__.py` file inside `templatetags` folder
3. Create `custom_tags.py`
4. Inside `custom_tags.py`, add the `prettydate` function

```
from django import template
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def prettydate(d):
    if d is not None:
    # the rest of the function
```

in template file,

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{{forumpost.max_activity|prettydate}}
```

Also make sure that you **restart the Django development server**. If the server does not restart, Django won't register the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can use template tags, by defining a new function formatted_date_text

```
{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"|formatted_date_text }}


def formatted_date_text(value):
    # define your funtion
```