# Any python/django libraries that convert datetime and timedeltas to phrases like "tonight at 8pm" or "tomorrow evening"?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking for a python or django library to give me humanized timedates to read like "tomorrow evening at 8pm" or "tonight at 8pm" or "next Monday at 8pm".

I've seen [django.contrib.humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/humanize/) and [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) but neither give that level of humanization. Does such a library exist? (Obviously not rocket science to write it myself, but I figure I'm not the first person to want such a thing...)

Comment: I found this python library [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/) and there is also this related question on SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410221/natural-relative-days-in-python

Comment: @Dugnom: dateparser seems to do the reverse: changing from text to variables.